# Selenium Invalid character '#' on ExecuteScript

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, phantomjs

I trying to run ExecuteScript ,and i geeting this error

```
Invalid character '#'
```

but i tested this script from console Fife-Fox(debug) all work.

This how i run script.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = browserToRun as IJavaScriptExecutor;
 js.ExecuteScript("'$('#accountListCell').find('option[value='123']').trigger( 'change' )'");
```

What i am doing wrong here?

I using PhantomJSDriver .

i tryed this to find error

```
string test= "$('\#accountListCell').find('option[value='123']').trigger( 'change' )
```

this what i get

```
$('#accountListCell').find('option[value='444-135777']').trigger( 'change' )
```

Comment: Check your quotation marks and escape them properly.

Comment: Use this: "$('\#accountListCell').find('option[value='123']').trigger( 'change' )"

Comment: try this : js.ExecuteScript("$('#accountListCell').find('option[value='123']').trigger('change');");

Comment: now i getting Expected token ')',but i checked there is no ")" is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing a script to the WebDriver. It must be a single string. You've used `"` quotes to provide the script. Let's look at the script that you provided:

```
'$('#accountListCell').find('option[value='123']').trigger( 'change' )'
```

The first thing that you notice is that the syntax highlighting is all wrong. `$` is not a string inside of the script, so it doesn't make sense to write it inside of a string. Remove the first and last `'`:

```
$('#accountListCell').find('option[value='123']').trigger( 'change' )
```

Now that's better. There is still a problem. If you look at the `find` argument, it is another substring. CSS strings can be wrapped in `'` as well as `"`. Sometimes you don't even need the quotation marks. Use either

```
$('#accountListCell').find('option[value=\"123\"]').trigger( 'change' )
```

because you have to escape `"` if you want to use it inside of a string that was wrapped in `"` or simply

```
$('#accountListCell').find('option[value=123]').trigger( 'change' )
```

Final:

```
js.ExecuteScript("$('#accountListCell').find('option[value=\"123\"]').trigger( 'change' )");
```